# Showing that function is not injective.

Tags: real-analysis

let

$f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \textrm{ with } U \subset \mathbb{R} \textrm{ x } \mathbb{R^k}$open, be a continuously differentiable function. Show that $f$ is not injective.

*Proof* : Proceed by contradiction. Assume that $f$ is injective. Then, $a \neq b \Rightarrow f(a) \neq f(b)$. Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, one of the partial derivatives, namely $f_{,1}$ or $f_{,2}$, are non zero. Here is where I get stuck. How do I prove that one of the partial derivatives is nonzero at a point?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since U is open, for $x_0 \in U$, we can always find a unit ball $B_r(x_0) \subset U$ for some $r > 0$. We also know the closed $\bar{B}_{r/2}(x_0) \subset B_r(x_0) \subset U$.

Since $\bar{B}_{r/2}(x_0)$ is closed and is also compact, function f has maximum and minimum on the closed ball. Let $x_m \in \bar{B}_{r/2}(x_0)$ be the minimum point such that $f(x_m) = m$; Let $x_M \in \bar{B}_{r/2}(x_0)$ be the maximum point such that $f(x_M) = M$. Let $x(t) = x_m +t(x_M - x_m)$, for $0\le t \le 1$, be the line segment connecting $x_m$ and $x_M$.Since the ball has more than one dimension, so we have another point $x_c$ in the ball, but not on the line segment x(t). Let $C = f(x_c)$. So $m \le C \le M$.

Now let us consider function $F(t) = f(x(t)) = f(x_m +t (x_M-x_m))$,
$F(0) = m \le F(1) = M$. Using intermediate value theorem, there exists a $t^*$, such that $F(t^*) = C = f(x_c) = f(x_m +t^* (x_M - x_m))$.

From our proof, we know $x_c \ne x_m +t^* (x_M - x_m)$.
QED

Answer (score 0):

To show that $f$ is not injective you just need to show it's not injective in the vicinity of one point.  Pick any point $x_0$ with $f'(x_0)\ne 0$.  (Note, $f'$ is a $(k+1)$-vector.)  We can always pick such a point unless $f$ is constant, in which case it's obviously not injective.

Consider $k=1$.  Consider the "easy version" of the implicit function theorem in Baby Rudin just before 9.26, which is as follows with some variables renamed to avoid confusion:  "the equation $g(u,v)=0$ can be solved for any $v$ in terms of $u$ in a neighborhood of any point $(a,b)$ at which $g(a,b)=0$ and $\partial g/\partial v\ne 0$."  From this it follows that $g$ is not injective in a neighborhood of $(a,b)$, since there are many points in that neighborhood which all map to $0$.

Because $f'(x_0)\ne 0$, we can if necessary make a rotational change of coordinates such that $\partial f/\partial v\ne 0$ -- this amounts to making the $v$ axis be the axis of the vector $f'(x_0)$.  Once that is done, we apply the easy implicit function theorem to $g(x)=f(x)-f(x_0)$ with $(a,b)=x_0$, and conclude that $g(x)$, and thus $f(x)$, is not injective in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

I believe the full theorem with $k>1$ follows from the full implicit function theorem, Baby Rudin 9.28.